# How do I calculate size measurements using loops?

Tags: python, loops, selection

[image: The image of the question]

I'm trying to code the question in the image above but I only know how to use if else and for, while loop.

Can't figure out how to use a loop for this so I tried if else, but ended up with 100+ lines just doing height < 155.

Can it be done using a loop?

This is my code, I stopped at height<155 due to the length:

```
height = float(input('Enter height measurement (cm): '))
chest = float(input('Enter Chest Measurement (cm): '))
waist = float(input('Enter waist measurement (cm): '))

if height < 155:
    if chest < 80:
        if waist < 70:
            print('You are size 1 (best fit)')
    elif chest >= 80 and chest < 88:
        if waist <70:
            print('You are size 2 (Regular fit)')
        elif waist >= 76 and waist < 84:
            print('You are size 3 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 84 and waist < 92:
            print('You are size 4 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 92 and waist < 100:
            print('You are size 5 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 100 and waist < 108:
            print('You are size 6 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 108 and waist < 116:
            print('You are size 7 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 116:
            print('You are size 8 (Relaxed fit)')

    elif chest >= 88 and chest < 96:
        if waist < 70:
            print('You are size 3 (Regular fit)')
        elif waist >= 84 and waist < 92:
            print('You are size 4 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 92 and waist < 100:
            print('You are size 5 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 100 and waist < 108:
            print('You are size 6 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 108 and waist < 116:
            print('You are size 7 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 116:
            print('You are size 8 (Relaxed fit)')
    elif chest >= 96 and chest < 104:
        if waist < 70:
            print('You are size 4 (Regular fit)')
        elif waist >= 92 and waist < 100:
            print('You are size 5 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 100 and waist < 108:
            print('You are size 6 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 108 and waist < 116:
            print('You are size 7 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 116:
            print('You are size 8 (Relaxed fit)')
    elif chest >= 104 and chest < 112:
        if waist < 70:
            print('You are size 5 (Regular fit)')
        elif waist >= 100 and waist < 108:
            print('You are size 6 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 108 and waist < 116:
            print('You are size 7 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 116:
            print('You are size 8 (Relaxed fit)')
    elif chest >= 112 and chest < 120:
        if waist < 70:
            print('You are size 6 (Regular fit)')
        elif waist >= 108 and waist < 116:
            print('You are size 7 (Relaxed fit)')
        elif waist >= 116:
            print('You are size 8 (Relaxed fit)')
    elif chest >= 120 and chest < 128:
        if waist < 70:
            print('You are size 7 (Regular fit)')
        elif waist >= 116:
            print('You are size 8 (Relaxed fit)')
    elif chest >= 128:
        if waist >=116:
            print('You are size 8 (Regular fit)')
        else:
            print('You are size 8 (Relaxed fit)')
```

Comment: How are you determining fit as a function of waist, chest, and height? Is there a formula? Is there a table you're referencing? These will determine how you best implement this.

Comment: What should the size be if, for example, height = 185?

Comment: Didn't you forget a few nested `if`s? E.g. `chest == 100 and waist == 80` won't match anything. If there's a formula (or otherwise logic), you can use it. Otherwise, you can store a dictionary that maps size descriptions to chest, waist, etc. ranges and then search the dictionary for a match. It seems, the most important detail that misses in your question is, where do you get these specific numbers from? That answer will likely be the solution to your problem then.

Comment: I suggest you learn about functions. You have some repeated code `if waist < 70...` that is a great candidate to put in a function. This allows you to write the code once and then use it over and over and over again.

Comment: @Kaia There is a table in the linked image

Comment: Looking at the image and the examples therein, this doesn't seem to be a hierarchical relationship (i.e. no need for nested conditions). Instead you need to determine the size for the three data points individually and then evaluate the actual size by considering the three individual ones.

Comment: You're missing the generalizations here. E.g., the height increases in steps of 5. Try to divide different heights by 5 using *floor division* (double slash `//`). For example, compare `157 // 5`,  `163 // 5`, `170 // 5`, etc. and you should start seeing a pattern. It's similar for the other ranges with one minor exception to the rule AFAICT. This should be possible in 10 - 20 lines of code max.

Comment: From the requirements you posted, I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Read the description careful and see what you can do without all the nested `if` statements.

Comment: I coded this up myself to see how simple it could be. At most you need a table with 3 columns and 8 rows, each column being `height`, `chest` and `waist`, and each row being just the minimum value for that column (for instance, row 0 is `(0, 0, 0)`, row 3 would be `(165, 96, 84)`. Then you just have to loop through a tuple of the user's 3 measurements, for each row in the table, and check if the user's measurement is within the range of that row's minimum value and the next row's minimum value. So, for the last row, you can just set your max to `math.inf`.

Comment: As for how to calculate the fit, I just did a big boolean expression - I took a tuple of the user's sizes, assigned each item to `a, b, c`, and then for example, for `regular` fit, the code would be `if (b == c and b > a): fit = 'regular'`. You'd have to cycle the values of `a`, `b`, and `c` 3 times, making sure that a different measurement is in each variable each time, so that you check all logical possibilities. For `relaxed` you'd just do `if (a > b and a > c)`, and for `best` that's the easiest - no need to loop - you just check `a == b == c`.

Comment: Also, my code for this ended up being 28 lines and it took about 45 minutes (while also trying to do my actual job in the background) so I know you can do this in far fewer lines and in far less time; you don't have to continue with your time-consuming original method.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the table, you can see a regular pattern. For instance, the height ranges are all of size 5 (155-160, 160-165, ...), except the "catch-all" at either extreme.

So you can calculate the corresponding size with a formula. For instance for height, we can first subtract 145 and then divide by 5. Then convert anything that is less than 1 to 1, and anything that is greater than 8 to 8.

For the chest measure, the steps are 8 wide. Similarly for the waist measure, the steps are 8 wide, but there is one exception: the waist range for size 2 is 70-76 and thus only spans 6 units, not 8. It would have been nice if that range had been 68-76. So there is special care needed to deal with that irregularity, so that 68 and 69 will translate to waist size 1 and not to size 2.

Secondly, the fit can be derived as follows:

Sort the three sizes (for height, chest and waist) and get the greatest value: that is the size to report. Then find the first occurrence of that size in the sorted list of sizes. If it is found at index 0, then the fitting is "best"; if it is found at index 1, the fitting is "regular", and if found at index 2, then it is "relaxed".

Here is the code for it:

```
height = float(input('Enter height measurement (cm): '))
chest = float(input('Enter Chest Measurement (cm): '))
waist = float(input('Enter waist measurement (cm): '))

height_size = min(8, max(1, int(height - 145) // 5)) 
chest_size = min(8, max(1, int(chest - 64) // 8))
waist_size = min(8, max(1, int(waist - 52) // 8))
if waist < 70:
    waist_size = 0  # Deal with an irregularity for waist measures 69 and 68.

sizes = sorted([height_size, chest_size, waist_size])
size = sizes[-1]  # Greatest
fitting = ["best", "regular", "relaxed"][sizes.index(size)]

print(f"You are size {size} ({fitting} fit)")
```